# Counta Query importrange within date parameters and if specific text is present

Tags: google-sheets-formula

In this sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xNFVHLnQGkRgZdLmejCyU0BByOPBY8NMoIYj6SkTFGY/edit#gid=1075801741

I am trying to count all rows from within https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xNFVHLnQGkRgZdLmejCyU0BByOPBY8NMoIYj6SkTFGY/edit#gid=431567503 which are the partner represented in A3 sheet2! and also within date range =>01/07/22 & =<01/09/22.

I have tried this which always returns 1 regardless of the dates or partner I enter:

```
=COUNTA(IFNA(QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("/1xNFVHLnQGkRgZdLmejCyU0BByOPBY8NMoIYj6SkTFGY/edit#gid=431567503", "July!A2:B")}, "where Col1='"&A3&"' & Col2 =>01/07/2022 & Col2 =<07/09/2022", 0)))
```

I think the problem lies with the way I have written the dates but I can't figure the correct way.

I need to importrange URL included as my live data is from another workbook.

Any suggestions appreciated

Updated:

Almost have what I need with this formula but it relies on the dates being available in Sheet2! which they wouldn't be for my need

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("/1xNFVHLnQGkRgZdLmejCyU0BByOPBY8NMoIYj6SkTFGY/edit#gid=431567503", "July!A2:B")}, 
                       "Select Col1 where Col1 contains '"&A$3&"' 
                                      and Col2>= date"&TEXT(F1,"'YYYY-MM-DD'")&" 
                                      and Col2<= date"&TEXT(G1,"'YYYY-MM-DD'")&"",0)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("/1xNFVHLnQGkRgZdLmejCyU0BByOPBY8NMoIYj6SkTFGY/edit#gid=431567503", "July!A2:B")}, 
                       "Select Col1 where Col1 contains '"&A3&"' 
                                      and Col2 >= date '2022-07-01' 
                                      and Col2 <= date '2022-07-01'" ,0)))
```